# How to fill the next drop down menu based on current selection in HTML?

Tags: html, sql, drop-down-menu, html-select

Im writing a HTML form to select a particular model of a mobile device. I want to create a database of televisions, mobiles, and computers. On selecting the mobile, I want the user to select the brand of mobiles, on selecting the brand, then model, then variant and so on. How to write the HTML file to make it function like this. Until the Brand is selected, the model should not be visible, after selecting the brand, the dropdown should allow to select models etc.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried mysql to create tables, and I want to know how to connect them to the HTML files?